# Rewrite URLs Using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Referring to the article [here](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls) I created my .htaccess file with the following lines

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/product/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?route=product&product=$1 [L]
```

but this doesn't work and I get a 404 error.

I want URLs like

```
http://localhost/product/12/some-random-text.html
```

to be redirected to

```
http://localhost/index.php?route=product&product=12
```

I am using `GoDaddy's` Linux hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?route=product&product=$1 [QSA,L]
```